# Add attribute not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add an `href` attribute to `a` element using jqueny when window size is less than 768 pixel

```
        <ul class="menu-link">
            <!--<li><a class="" href="#">HOME</a></li>-->
            <li><a id="#about-us" >ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a id="#contact" >CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      var windowSize = $(window).width(); // 
            if (windowSize < 768) {
                //add attr
                $("#about-us").attr("href", "#about-us");
                $("#contact").attr("href", "#contact");
    }
});
```

It is not working for some reason am i doing something wrong

Comment: also you have `id="#about-us"` and `id="#contact"`. It should just be `id="about-us"` and `id="contact"`

Comment: why don't you use media query?

Comment: Using media query then i have to repeat whole set of html code twice. for this reason i want to do it with jquery.

Comment: *"It is not working for some reason am i doing something wrong"* Yeah, i'm sure that's why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to remove the `#` from the ids:

```
<li><a id="#about-us" >ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a id="#contact" >CONTACT</a></li>
```

Should be

```
<li><a id="about-us" >ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a id=contact" >CONTACT</a></li>
```

Next, you probably want to run that on window.resize as well:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    var add_remove = $(window).width() < 768; 
    $("#about-us").attr("href", add_remove ? "#about-us" : "");
    $("#contact").attr("href", add_remove ? "#contact" : "");
  });
  $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

to show what @pattmorter is pointing out

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu-link">
        <!--<li><a class="" href="#">HOME</a></li>-->

        <!-- remove the # from the ids -->
        <li><a id="about-us" >ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a id="contact" >CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var windowSize = $(window).width(); // 
        if (windowSize < 768) {
            //add attr
            $("#about-us").attr("href", "#about-us");
            $("#contact").attr("href", "#contact");
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just made a stupid mistake... didn't notice that i am adding `#` with `id=#about-us`.. stress of overwork..

Comment: I think we have all been there... Cheers!